# MS SQL. Как проверить на null ВСЕ столбцы таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица (напр.,"Table"), в ней 60 столбцов.

Я знаю, как проверить 1 (или несколько) столбец:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'Table' 
WHERE'p1' IS NULL
```

Но у меня таких столбцов очень много. И все их вписывать в условие WHERE таким способом займет ооочень много времени.
Как проверить на NULL сразу все столбцы таблицы, при этом не вписывая их названия вручную в запрос SQL? Надо уместить это в один запрос, при этом способ: копировать названия столбцов и тупо самой их вставить в WHERE - не подходит.

Может, можно это сделать при помощи след. запроса:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
```

Этот запрос выводит названия всех столбцов таблицы.

Comment: Список полей получили? ну теперь используйте этот список в запросе.

Comment: Как??? Если бы знала как это сделать, то не задала бы этот вопрос...

Comment: Вместо "вписывания в условие WHERE таким способом", которое "займет ооочень много времени", скопипастите полученный список в запрос.

Comment: ну не прям список а `select (COLUMN_NAME + 'IS NULL OR ' )`

Comment: либо пишите динамический sql запрос и выполняете его, если все манипуляции надо выполнить программно